# How to dynamically create a UserScript in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, userscripts

I want to distribute a UserScript to a number of people, however I need my script to be created dynamically (using PHP) as certain parameters will change.

I have a template script; in this script I have a couple of parameters that will be filled in on the fly, for example, in the template:

```
var a_parameter = "__tmp_aparam__";
```

I will then load the script into PHP, and replace those paramters:

```
$script = file_get_contents('priv/template.js');
$new_script = str_replace('__tmp_aparam__','a_value',$script);
echo $new_script;
```

This will create the script how I want it, however, it isn't downloadable. How can I make the PHP script create a *.user.js file which browsers (like chrome), will automatically download and install?

Is there a header property I can set to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Suffix the URL by `.user.js` and serve the file using mime-type `application/javascript`.

Userscript managers recognise User scripts via the `.user.js` extension.

Screenshot: Triggering Greasemonkey's installation by suffixing a random JavaScript file with `.user.js`:

[image: Screenshot showing Greasemonkey getting triggered by a random JS file with an appended <code>.user.js</code> suffix]

Comment: but if I change the extension then the PHP code won't execute?

Comment: @AlexCoplan The code will not execute, unless the user confirms it. See my attached screenshot for suffixing `.user.js` to an arbitrary JavaScript file.

Comment: I'm not talking about JS code - I'm talking about PHP code - the server won't execute any server-side code unless the extension is PHP, or the server has been told to execute PHP code in files of other types, but I've just realised I can rewrite the URL to match a PHP file on the server-side, so that solves that issue

Comment: I wonder if script.php?.user.js would work the same as Rob W's example above?

Comment: @Kato It does in Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760412/209139 for a way to serve a `.php` script without a `.php` file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Under php manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

a comment by:

Cody G.01-Aug-2010 09:53

includes the following code for creating downloads by playing with php header:

```
<?php
  if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
   header("Content-type: text/javascript");
   header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"download.js\"");
   header("Content-Length: ".filesize("my-file.js"));
  } else {
   header("Content-type: application/force-download");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"download.js\"");
   header("Content-Length: ".filesize("my-file.js"));
  }
  header("Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2010 05:00:00 GMT");
  if(strstr($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],"MSIE")==false) {
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
  }
  include("my-file.js");
 ?>
```

I guess instead of the following command:

```
include("my-file.js");
```

There should be your code:

```
$script = file_get_contents('priv/template.js');     
$new_script = str_replace('__tmp_aparam__','a_value',$script);     
echo $new_script;
```

and download.js must be something.user.js

PS: I am unable to test this code now, any comments would be appreciated