# Removing .php extension in URLs but using subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, subdirectory, redirect

I want to redirect a URL to a php file in a subdirectory but am not able to do it. I tried everything but could not get it to work. What should I write in `.htaccess`?

Actually I want to do this: The URL `http://example.org/sub1/sub2/page` should access the file `http://example.org/sub1/sub2/page.php`, and I want to make this generic since I have multiple URLs like this to redirect to PHP files.

Basically I want to remove the `.php` extension from my URL.

Comment: "Tried everything". Tried *what*? Show your attempts.

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1760412/209139.