# Strip file extension from URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to figure out how I can strip the file extension from the url.
I want to change www.website.com/index.php to show www.website.com/index.

I have been trying to get this to work

```
RewriteRule ^about$ about.php [L]
```

When I plug this code in to an htaccess file all it does is distort my website, actually it looks like it removes the css, weird..

I'm running my website locally on a wamp server.

Any advice on how I can get this to work?

Comment: Duplicate of [Hide Page Extensions (Like StackOverflow)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1759420/209139) or of [How can I use .htaccess to hide .php URL extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10028025/209139).

Comment: I tried that code, and I'm not getting the errors anymore, but the extensions are still there.

Comment: Those `.htaccess` scripts will make pages work both *with* and *without* file extensions. They won't redirect pages with extensions to ones without. Change your links to not include file extensions, and everything should work.

Comment: Any advice on changing requests like this (website.com/profile?name=christian) to (website.com/profile/christian).

Comment: That's been asked here before somewhere too. Try searching for htaccess rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely a result of you use relative paths for linking your stylesheets.  Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

When you visit `http://example.com/about/`, the web browser is looking for the stylesheet in: `http://example.com/about/css/style.css`.

To fix this, use absolute paths, which start from your web root:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Note:  you will probably have to use absolute paths for your images as well.

Comment: It's not property etiquette to entirely change your question after answers have been posted, however, the internal server error issue may be caused by Apache not having mod_rewrite enabled.  Can you verify that it is?

Comment: The style was working fine, then I got a server error.. changing the question was removing a problem I didn't have anymore. I will check to see if it is.

Comment: I changed
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
to LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and reset wamp. Still nothing :/

Comment: Got it working, my bad. I was still on index.php, and when I removed the .php it worked..

Comment: Is there anyway to auto direct to index from index.php, just in case they specified it.

Comment: @ChristianRankin: Perhaps something along the lines of: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1`

Comment: @ChristianRankin. If there's a problem you don't have any more, **don't** remove it from the question. Instead, mark the question as answered. Stack Overflow is not your personal debugging service: we expect questions and answers to provide value to other people too. Don't remove them when *you* don't need them any more.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

try adding these lines to .htacess in root of your site